# How to invert a matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I want to invert matrix a but its not working. I need help.

```js
var a = math.inv([[1,2],[3,4]])
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Are you trolling or something? There are so many errors in the code example, that it feels intentional?

Comment: Are you using another library?  Math.inv() isn't a function.

Comment: there is no `Var`, there is no `Document`. Case matters. And there is no `inv` method.

Comment: @Brett84c: I think the OP forgot to mention that he/she uses [the math.js library](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) does **not contain a `inv` method**. Therefore you cannot call it.

You can however define your own matrix inversion method as is done [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20210406035905/http://blog.acipo.com/matrix-inversion-in-javascript/), or you could use the [numeric JavaScript library](http://www.numericjs.com/) and call it with:

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,3,9]];
Ainv = numeric.inv(A);
```

or use [the `math.js` library](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html) and call it with:

```
math.inv([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Notice that you need a surrounding the list of lists with square brackets (here written in boldface).

In that case, a *minimal working example* would look like:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="result">loading result...</p>
  <script>
  var inverted = math.inv([[1,2],[3,4]]);
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(inverted);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is a perfect example of why you should provide short summaries of content from links since links will die

Comment: @JonasV: or just use the wayback machine :) http://web.archive.org/web/20210406035905/http://blog.acipo.com/matrix-inversion-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Your array that represents a matrix should be an array of arrays. Try [math.js](https://mathjs.org/) like this:

```
var a = math.inv([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Comment: What is the library used here?

Comment: I think he is using math.js

Comment: But not worth of mentioning in the answer?